# Using array_chunk on multi array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array and i am now sure how to use array chunk on my array key request while preserving the information into the new array. I would like to split the array every 2 arrays. I tried using array_chunk inside of a loop but no luck.

Here is my array.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => Richard
        [patient_first_name] => Donna
        [trip_date] => 2018-08-24
        [request] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 46
                    [client_id] => 9873
                    [city] => COOLIDGE
                    [state] => AZ
                    [zip] => 85228
                )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 49
                    [client_id] => 14965
                    [city] => CHANDLER
                    [state] => AZ
                    [zip] => 85226
                )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 55
                    [client_id] => 10120
                    [city] => PHX
                    [state] => AZ
                    [zip] => 85008
                )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 59
                    [client_id] => 11229
                    [city] => BUCKEYE
                    [state] => AZ
                    [zip] => 85326
                )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 69
                    [client_id] => 13769
                    [city] => PHOENIX
                    [state] => AZ
                    [zip] => 85035
                )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 175
                    [client_id] => 16437
                    [city] => Phx
                    [state] => Az
                    [zip] => 85029
                )

                [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 195
                    [client_id] => 16457
                    [city] => Apache Junction
                    [state] => Az
                    [zip] => 85120
                )

                [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 197
                    [client_id] => 16459
                    [city] => Mesa
                    [state] => Az
                    [zip] => 85204
                )

            )

        )
```

This is the array I would like.

```
 [0] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Richard
                [patient_first_name] => Donna
                [trip_date] => 2018-08-24
                [request] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 46
                            [client_id] => 9873
                            [city] => COOLIDGE
                            [state] => AZ
                            [zip] => 85228
                        )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 49
                            [client_id] => 14965
                            [city] => CHANDLER
                            [state] => AZ
                            [zip] => 85226
                        )
)

        [1] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Richard
                [patient_first_name] => Donna
                [trip_date] => 2018-08-24
                [request] => Array    
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 55
                            [client_id] => 10120
                            [city] => PHX
                            [state] => AZ
                            [zip] => 85008
                        )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 59
                            [client_id] => 11229
                            [city] => BUCKEYE
                            [state] => AZ
                            [zip] => 85326
                        )
)
    [2] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Richard
                [patient_first_name] => Donna
                [trip_date] => 2018-08-24
                [request] => Array
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 69
                            [client_id] => 13769
                            [city] => PHOENIX
                            [state] => AZ
                            [zip] => 85035
                        )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 175
                            [client_id] => 16437
                            [city] => Phx
                            [state] => Az
                            [zip] => 85029
                        )

                    )

                )
```

This is my code.

```
$drivers = [];

        foreach($recs as $val => $rec) {
            $drivers[$rec->driver_id]['first_name'] = $rec->first_name;
            $drivers[$rec->driver_id]['patient_first_name'] = $rec->patient_first_name;
            $drivers[$rec->driver_id]['trip_date'] = $rec->trip_date;
            $drivers[$rec->driver_id]['request'][] = $rec;
        }

        foreach($drivers as $val => $driver) {
            $drivers = array_chunk($driver['request'], 2);
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: ...sorry, \I had to go away just after commenting on your now-deleted question.  I am happy to see that you got `array_chunk()` to work.  It is the best tool for the job.  (this question is written much better/clearer than your earlier post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [array-chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) if what you need. Check the following example (I remove some of the data to simplify):

```
$request = array(["id" => 46], ["id" => 49], ["id" => 55], ["id" => 59], ["id" => 69], ["id" => 175], ["id" => 195], ["id" => 197]);
$arr[] = array("first_name" => "Richard", "request" => $request);
foreach($arr as $driver) {
    $requests = array_chunk($driver['request'], 2);
    foreach($requests as $chunck) {
        $ans[] = array("id" => $driver["first_name"], "request" => $chunck); // here you  can add all the other data you need from the "driver" object
    }
}
```

Now , `$ans` will have your desire output

Comment: That was only example - you can ignore the first 2 line of my code and use your array

Answer (score 1):

Get 'request' from the source array, chunk it and add rest items to each element of the result array

```
$res = array_chunk($recs['request'], 2);
unset($recs['request']);

foreach($res as &$x)  {
   $x += $recs;
}
```

Comment: $drivers would the source I made some changes but I am getting an error back saying expects parameter 1, the function clearly does have a value.

$res = array_chunk($drivers['request'], 2);
            unset($drivers['request']);

            foreach($res as &$x)  {
                $x += $drivers;
            }